# C++14 Thread Pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++14

I have written the following thread pool implementation in C++14.

It appears to work fine on my system, but I am looking for a second opinion on the thread safety of my implementation and any other possible implementation flaws or concerns.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


template<typename... event_args>
class thread_pool{
public:

    using handler_type = std::function<void(event_args...)>;

    thread_pool(handler_type&& handler, std::size_t N = 4): _handler(std::forward<handler_type&&>(handler)),_workers(N),_running(true)
    {
        for(auto&& worker: _workers)
        {
            worker = std::thread([this]()
            {
                while (_running)
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk{_wait_mutex};

                    _cv.wait(_lk, [this]{
                        return !_events.empty();
                    });

                    //a copy must be done here
                    auto data = _events.front();
                    //becauce the pop will invalidate any reference that we keep instead of copying
                    _events.pop();

                    _lk.unlock();

                    _cv.notify_all();

                    //call the handler with the data
                    invoke(std::move(_handler), std::move(data));

                }
            });

            worker.detach();
        }
    }

    ~thread_pool()
    {
        _running=false;

        _cv.notify_all();

        for(auto&& _worker: _workers)
        {
            if(_worker.joinable())
            {
                _worker.join();
            }
        }
    }

    handler_type& handler()
    {
        return _handler;
    }

    void propagate(event_args&&... args)
    {
        //lock before push
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk(_push_mutex);
        {
            _events.emplace(std::make_tuple(args...));
        }
        _lk.unlock();//explicit unlock
        _cv.notify_all();//let worker know that data is available
    }

private:

    handler_type _handler;

    std::queue<std::tuple<event_args...>> _events;

    std::vector<std::thread> _workers;

    std::atomic_bool _running;

    std::condition_variable _cv;

    std::mutex _wait_mutex;

    std::mutex _push_mutex;


    //helpers used to unpack tuple into function call
    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    auto invoke_(Func&& func, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return func(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple&&>(t))...);
    }

    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, typename Indicies = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>>
    auto invoke(Func&& func, Tuple&& t)
    {
        return invoke_(std::forward<Func&&>(func), std::forward<Tuple&&>(t), Indicies());
    }
};
```

With an example main:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::mutex writemtx;


    thread_pool<int> pool{
        [&](int i){
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{writemtx};
            std::cout<<i<<" : "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
        }
    };

    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i) {
        pool.propagate(std::move(i));
    }


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Which on my system produces an output of:

> ```
> 0 : 0x70000c42d000
> 1 : 0x70000c533000
> 2 : 0x70000c5b6000
> 3 : 0x70000c4b0000
> 4 : 0x70000c42d000
> 5 : 0x70000c533000
> 6 : 0x70000c5b6000
> 7 : 0x70000c4b0000
> 8 : 0x70000c42d000
> 9 : 0x70000c533000
> 10 : 0x70000c5b6000
> 11 : 0x70000c4b0000
> 12 : 0x70000c42d000
> 13 : 0x70000c533000
> 14 : 0x70000c5b6000
> 15 : 0x70000c4b0000
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor simply won't work reliably:

```
~thread_pool()
{
    _running=false;

    _cv.notify_all();

    for(auto&& _worker: _workers)
    {
        if(_worker.joinable())
        {
            _worker.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Let's have a look at your worker threads to see why:

```
while (_running)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk{_wait_mutex};

    _cv.wait(_lk, [this]{
        return !_events.empty();
    });
    ...
}
```

Even when you set `_running=false`, any worker thread waiting on `_cv` can't exit the wait as the wait condition won't be fulfilled.

Only threads which were already inside `_handler` at the time of invocation can even reach the loop condition and hence terminate.

Which means your destructor can get caught in a deadlock.

---

Well, at least it could if you hadn't called `worker.detach()`. Because of that, `joinable()` now returns false.

Instead of a deadlock you now have something far worse: **Use after free!**

As the thread pool is destroyed, all the mutexes, `_cv`, `_events`, `_handler` and `_running` are destroyed despite being still in use by the worker threads.

The next allocation reusing these memory sections, will result in a bloody mess.

---

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk(_push_mutex);
_events.emplace(std::make_tuple(args...));
```

VS

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk{_wait_mutex};
...
auto data = _events.front();
_events.pop();
```

You must use the same mutex to protect access to `_events`, right now it's not even guaranteed that changes to `_event` propagate ***at all***.

---

```
void propagate(event_args&&... args)
{
    ....
    _cv.notify_all()
}
```

Why `notify_all()`?

Only one work item was added, so `notify_one`suffices completely. Any additional worker threads waking on the notification will just have to go back to sleep as `_events` is already empty again once they obtain the mutex.

---

---

So in in summary with the proposed fixes included:

```
template<typename... event_args>
class thread_pool{
public:

    using handler_type = std::function<void(event_args...)>;

    thread_pool(handler_type&& handler, std::size_t N = 4) :
        _handler(std::forward<handler_type&&>(handler)),
        _workers(N),
        _running(true)
    {
        for(auto&& worker: _workers)
        {
            //worker function
            worker = std::thread([this]()
            {
                while (_running)
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk(_events_mutex);

                    //wait for work
                    _cv.wait(_lk, [this]{
                        return !_events.empty() || !_running;
                    });
                    //_lk is locked

                    //check to see why we woke up
                    if(!_running){//was it a signal to exit
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!_events.empty()) {//was it new work
                        auto data = _events.front();
                        _events.pop();

                        //Unlock _lk after changes to _events are done
                        _lk.unlock();

                        invoke(std::move(_handler), std::move(data));
                    }
                }
            });
            //end worker function
        }
    }

    ~thread_pool()
    {
        _running=false;

        //let all workers know to exit
        _cv.notify_all();

        //attempt to join all workers
        for(auto&& _worker: _workers)
        {
            if(_worker.joinable())
            {
                _worker.join();
            }
        }
    }

    handler_type& handler()
    {
        return _handler;
    }

    void propagate(event_args&&... args)
    {
        {
            //lock before push
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk(_events_mutex);
            _events.emplace(std::make_tuple(args...));
        }
        _cv.notify_one();//let worker know that data is available
    }

private:

    handler_type _handler;

    std::queue<std::tuple<event_args...>> _events;

    std::mutex _events_mutex;

    std::vector<std::thread> _workers;

    std::atomic_bool _running;

    std::condition_variable _cv;


    //helpers used to unpack tuple into function call
    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    auto invoke_(Func&& func, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return func(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple&&>(t))...);
    }

    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, typename Indicies = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>>
    auto invoke(Func&& func, Tuple&& t)
    {
        return invoke_(std::forward<Func&&>(func), std::forward<Tuple&&>(t), Indicies());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Ext3h I have modified my code to the following:

```
template<typename... event_args>
class thread_pool{
public:

    using handler_type = std::function<void(event_args...)>;

    thread_pool(handler_type&& handler, std::size_t N = 4): _handler(std::forward<handler_type&&>(handler)),_workers(N),_running(true)
    {
        for(auto&& worker: _workers)
        {
            //worker function
            worker = std::thread([this]()
            {
                while (_running)
                {
                    //wait for work
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk{_wait_mutex};
                    _cv.wait(_lk, [this]{
                        return !_events.empty() || !_running;
                    });
                    //_lk unlocked

                    //check to see why we woke up
                    if (!_events.empty()) {//was it new work
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _readlk(_queue_mutex);
                        auto data = _events.front();
                        _events.pop();
                        _readlk.unlock();

                        invoke(std::move(_handler), std::move(data));
                    }else if(!_running){//was it a signal to exit
                        break;
                    }
                    //or was it spurious and we should just ignore it
                }
            });
            //end worker function
        }
    }

    ~thread_pool()
    {

        _running=false;

        //let all workers know to exit
        _cv.notify_all();


        //attempt to join all workers
        for(auto&& _worker: _workers)
        {
            if(_worker.joinable())
            {
                _worker.join();
            }
        }
    }

    handler_type& handler()
    {
        return _handler;
    }

    void propagate(event_args&&... args)
    {
        //lock before push
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lk(_queue_mutex);
        {
            _events.emplace(std::make_tuple(args...));
        }
        _lk.unlock();//explicit unlock
        _cv.notify_one();//let worker know that data is available
    }

private:

    handler_type _handler;

    std::queue<std::tuple<event_args...>> _events;

    std::vector<std::thread> _workers;

    std::atomic_bool _running;

    std::condition_variable _cv;

    std::mutex _wait_mutex;

    std::mutex _queue_mutex;


    //helpers used to unpack tuple into function call
    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    auto invoke_(Func&& func, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return func(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple&&>(t))...);
    }

    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, typename Indicies = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>>
    auto invoke(Func&& func, Tuple&& t)
    {
        return invoke_(std::forward<Func&&>(func), std::forward<Tuple&&>(t), Indicies());
    }
};
```

Changes:

- Removed call to `detach()`
- Updated wait condition to watch for
  changes in `_running`
- Added condition check to make sure new data is
  available before trying to do work.
- Changed `notify_all()` to
  `notify_one()` in `propagate()`

Comment: That's not true: `//_lk unlocked`. `_lk` is unlocked while waiting, but it's guaranteed to be locked again once exiting the wait. There are no spurious wakes either, when using the predicate parameter for `wait()`. Using `_queue_mutex` and `_wait_mutex` is still wrong! As I said before, changes to `_events` made in `propagate` under `_queue_mutex` are ***not*** guaranteed to be visible when synchronizing the condition variable on `_wait_mutex` instead.

Comment: So with your changes, there is now effectively only a single worker active at a time, as `_lk` is locked once the predicate is fulfilled, and it remains locked until the scope is exited, which is only after `invoke()` returns.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with an example of the correct way to implement what you are describing? I am having a tough time trying to follow your explanations

Comment: From what I am gathering from your comments, I should use the same mutex for propagate and for the wait lock?

Comment: Correct. Perhaps it becomes clearer when you just call it `_events_mutex`, as the role of the mutex is to avoid data races on a specific data structure, in this case `_events`. You need to obtain a lock on that mutex for all accesses to `_events`, regardless of whether you are writing or just reading.

Comment: Despite running being a _mutex it's a constraint of `condition_variables` that you need to hold the relevant lock when modifying the data relevant to the predicate. That doesn't take place in the destructor.